# Angular - Date pipe

Tags: angular, date, typescript

I'm trying to show a date correctly on IE in Angular. It's working fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc., but not on IE. This is my code :

```
<span>{{menu.modifiedDate ? (menu.modifiedDate | date : "dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss") : '-'}}</span>
```

This is what Google Chrome is showing :

```
15-06-2017 08:39:39
```

And this is what IE is showing :

```
15-06-2017 08:00:6/15/2017 8:39:39 AM:6/15/2017 8:39:39 AM
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: I think you are missing brackets around the condition to left of question mark

Answer (score 2):

That is an old issue
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13880

You might be working with an old version. Upgrading to the latest stable version should fix the problem.

Comment: And btw, this is probably not a bug with Angular but with IE. So I don't know what you mean by upgrading to the latest version should fix the bug IE is doing..

Comment: Explain in details your answer, add this line I'll accept as the answer. (https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Problem solved on the recent versions of Angular. Which version of Angular are you using? (see 'package.json' file)

Comment: I'm using 4.0.3. This is not an Angular bug.

Comment: The problem is related to the format that you pass the required date to the Date() object. For some reason IE and safari surprisingly do not support this date format.
try this 

<span>{{menu.modifiedDate ? (menu.modifiedDate | date : "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") : '-'}}</span>

or my method in the answer

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue on IE. The best solution is to create your own pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @pipe({
    name: 'date'
    })

    export class DataPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {

        let dd = value.substr(8, 2);
        let MM = value.substr(5, 2);
        let yyyy = value.substr(0, 4);
        let date = `${dd}/${MM}/${yyyy}`;

        return `${date}`;
    }
    }`
```

With this it should solve your problem.

Comment: How I use it ?  :)

Comment: You put this part of code in your component and use the the key name 'date' in your HTML part 
for example : <pre> {{ date }} </pre>